# Updating multiple databases based on deployment settings

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a content management system that 5 sites are using with 5 different databases. The project is in .NET using entity framework.

Every time a database change is made I have to go manually on all databases and add the change to each one of them. I would like to change this.

But the requirements are that the code can not be executed within the project on the server for security reasons.

If taken a look at the techniques  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465343(v=vs.100).aspx) but following that I would neet to remember to change the connection string each time.

I also thought of a batch script but How would I know what the destination server is.

The only thing that should be done is make a file with the database changes and 
the when you publish, the changes should be made on the server that I am publishing to.

is this somehow possible?

Comment: do you use TFS..? if so create a Database Project that houses all of the 5 databases and in the TFS deploy / build script propagate your changes that way.. if not sounds like you will need to build / generate some sql scripts that you can execute via C# in some secure fashion

Comment: Redgate has some cool tools, I used the multi script app at my last placed and loved it. [link](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DACPAC, for deploying projects from your source control. Either it can be TFS or VSO. You can build for different environments and deploy database projects based on targets. You can automate to continuous integration and continuous deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nant for you configuration,try the link below

[Targeting multiple environments through NAnt](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/01/02/targeting-multiple-environments-through-nant/)